# how to delay the google auto complete to save credit

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

As you know every time when we type the google map autoComplete will fire, I want to set a delay for this, such as 250ms,so give user more time to type and also save the credits.

Comment: A 250ms delay wouldn't make a difference; if you're using session tokens (as you should), then you're billed per Autocomplete session, not per character. Please refer to Google's billing documentation https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#ac-with-details-session